# swap 2 finger tap and 3 finger

Tags: touchpad, dconf

Is is possible to swap these two taps without affecting anything else ?

In latest gnome, as far as i know, it is possible to remap using a dconf setting,
`org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad.tap-button-map`

which isnt available in elemantary os 6

Comment: Are you sure it is not available? I can see on my installation the key is there, and it is set to 'default'. It also lists other 2 possible values: 'lrm' and 'lmr'

Comment: its not, just did a fresh first time install of elemantry os 6 and this was like one of the first thing I wanted to change coming from sway

Comment: Hmmm, maybe it was added for me when I installed Touché (a GUI for touchégg) https://flathub.org/apps/details/com.github.joseexposito.touche It allows more indepth configs of the touchpad gestures.

Comment: installed it as well and its still not there. any way to add/import these settings directly ?

Comment: This is highly strange. I can see and configure that key in dconf, but it is not listed in the output of 'gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad'.... Unfortunately I do not know how the key was added in my installation, but I suspect it is ignored. In Touchee, under the 'Tap' section, there is a notification: "Tap gestures are only available on touchscreens. Tapping on the touchpad is not available."

Comment: on gnome, I can indeed sway the tap behaviour by using changing 'lmr' to 'lrm' or vice versa, does it have any effect on yours ?